# How to scroll to item using Scrollview when mounting?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to use to a particular item in a list. Ive been reading and looking at all kinds of examples but nothing works. Could someone please tell me how to make it work? Thanks !!!

```
const Screen = ({id, data}) => {
    const [y, setY] = useState(null);
    const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data.length > 0 && id && y) {
            if (scrollViewRef.current && scrollViewRef.current !== null) {
                const index = data.findIndex(item => {
                    return item._id === id
                });
                if (index >= 0) {
                     scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({
                     y: data.length * index, animated: true
                });
            }
        }
     }
    }, [data, id, y]);


   return (
       <ScrollView  ref={scrollViewRef>
  <View style={{height: 900, backgroundColor: "red"}}></View> //this height is not fixed and would vary
       <>
           {data.length > 0 && data.map((item, key) => {
               return (
                   <View
                       key={key}
                       style={{height: 250, backgroundColor: colors.green, margin: 20}}
                       onLayout={(event) => {
                           const layout = event.nativeEvent.layout;
                           setY(layout.y)
                       }}>
                       <Text >{data.name}</Text>
                   </View>
               )
           })}
     </>
       </ScrollView>
   ) 
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a quick solution:

On some occasions, updateScroll might be called before layoutRef update. recalling  updateScroll with a small setTimeout delay would help with this issue.

```
const ScrollToIndex = ({ id , data = [] }) => {
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);
  const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);
  const layoutRef = useRef([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    updateScroll();
  }, [data, id, isReady]);

  const updateScroll = (count = 0) => {
    if (!id || !isReady || count > 2) return;

    const index = data.findIndex((item) => item._id === id);
    if (index === -1) return;

    if (scrollViewRef.current && layoutRef.current[index] > -1)
      return scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({
        y: layoutRef.current[index],
        animated: true,
      });

    const myTimeOut = setTimeout(() => {
      updateScroll(count + 1);
      clearTimeout(myTimeOut);
    }, 20);
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView ref={scrollViewRef}>
      <View style={{ height: 900, width: 5 }} />
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <View
          key={index}
          style={{ height: 250, backgroundColor: "green", margin: 20 }}
          onLayout={({ nativeEvent: { layout } }) => {
            layoutRef.current[index] = layout.y;
            if (index === data.length - 1) setIsReady(true);
          }}
        >
          <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        </View>
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

In your example, re-rendering is triggered by setY multiple times, equal to the length of the data array. It might cause performance issues.

In general, [React suggest that useEffect might not be the best practice for these situations.](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#adjusting-some-state-when-a-prop-changes)

scrollTo could be tricky, I use it in conjunction with onLayout. If the item heights are fixed, it's simply a matter of postponing the scroll until the ScrollView is mounted.

```
const scrollItemHeight = 250 + 20 * 2;

const ScrollToIndex = ({ id, data = sampleList }) => {   
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);
  const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);      

  if (isMounted && shouldScroll) {
      // get Index and scroll to index * scrollItemHeight
  }

  const onLayout = () => {
    if(!isMounted) setIsMounted(true);
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView ref={scrollViewRef} onLayout={onLayout}>
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <View
        // with key style as above without onLayout         
        >
          <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        </View>
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your code works great (the first example as the height is not fixed), just when Im scrolling to the first item/with index 0, it doesnt scroll (im rendering other content before the ScrollView, so the first item is not on top of page or so). How can I fix this?

Comment: actually I just noticed of course it makes sense, because I calculate y * index and if index is null, y becomes 0. So I tried now to set scrollHeight / 2 which seems to work, but is there more a reliable way for the first item?

Comment: When y is zero it  should scroll to the top. If you have other views inside ScrollView, you can store first two items  and calculate height or simply store  all items y and scroll to y index. _I have update the example it should cover for dynamic heights and other views inside ScrollView now_

Comment: So with the updated code, it doesnt scroll at all anymore (no matter if first item or not). I also updated my code, just to show that where the other content would be

Comment: Well I just found out on one real device it doesn't work. Apparently, update scroll is called before layoutRef updates. The solution would be recalling the update. _I updated the answer, please check_

Comment: I haven't realised it before because I always call scroll with delay for UX.

Comment: Thank you!!! So I tested just your code without my data and it actually did work (also the code before your update) and I tested on ios real device. Did you perhaps test it on android real device where it didnt work? Also, so now the code works (also with my own code/data. It scrolls correctly, just that it doesnt always exactly scroll down to the beginning of the item. With your sample data, where each item has same size, it scroll perfectly to beginning of the item, with my data (since the height varies a little), it scrolls differently (sometimes its beginning, middle or somewhere in btw)

Comment: No problem! I tested with Android low end and it was fine. It was only with iOS real that had problem with previous code. The code should work fine even if the heights are different, except if the heights change while or just before scroll, which could be fixed with a setTimeout. Or if the margins are different the y in layout is below top margin